# Google Script on sheets - onEdit script that merges the cell edited to the column preceding it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to have my sheet merge two values once a new value is entered in specific columns.

At the moment I am only trying to work on the first part... but I am failing

```
    function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var editedColumn = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();



    if(editedColumn==5 &&  
     e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Table1') 
  {    

 var String1 = e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue()
 var string2 = e.range.offset(0,0).getValue() 
 var value = [String1+" / "+string2]

 // This is just to check if the value is correct   
   Logger.log(value);   

//This is where the code is not working/breaking

 e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(value);

  e.range.offset(0,0).clear();
    }

}
```

Why is "e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(value);" not working?

And what if I want to add multiple possible columns that trigger this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Not working" could mean a lot of different things. Are there any errors being thrown? What do the logs show? Please be more specific.

Comment: I've tried your code and it's working fine for me. Do you get any errors when you run it? Is this "once a new value is entered in specific columns" done by code or do you do it manually?

Comment: NOT WORKINg means that if I leave that in, I see no action happening on the sheet. Column -1 Does not get updated. And Column 0 Does not get cleared.  I get no error. The LOG shows the correct values. IF instead, I remove that line, the code works and it CLEARS the amended cells. So my assumption is that the code "breaks" there. I tried adding a date instead of a specific value, and it worked...

Comment: ... I just realised that was a DATA VALIDATION clause on column -1 and that is what was blocking the script!

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of minor changes but it's working for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='Sheet3') {    
    var String1=e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue()
    var string2 = e.value;
    var value = String1+" / "+string2;
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(value);
    e.range.clear();
  }
}
```

Here's my section of validation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I realised the issue I was having was due to a data validation clause on the target cell! Any idea on how I can make this work with multiple columns?

Comment: What kind of data validation did you have?

Comment: I added data validation to a section of column five and it still seems to work fine for me.  It's okay to clear the data validation.  It would be a problem if you were inserting data that wasn't valid but then you'll get the validation errors.

Comment: I removed data validation, it was limiting it to a list of values. It was a mistake. THANK YOU!